# OrientDB performance testing disable cache

Tags: java, caching, orientdb

I have written some performance testing on an embedded orientdb database v1.7.7.

The same query is executed several times. The first query execution take some times but the subsequent executions are much more faster.

I guess that OrientDB is caching a lot of things. So i want to disable the cache.

The documentation on [orientdb caching](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Caching#disable-local-cache) says that:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.CACHE_LOCAL_ENABLED.setValue(false);
```

I had to adapt this code since this configuration property does not exists, so i wrote:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.CACHE_LEVEL1_ENABLED.setValue(false);
OGlobalConfiguration.CACHE_LEVEL2_ENABLED.setValue(false);
```

But even with this configuration my problem remains. *The first query execution take some times but the subsequent executions are much more faster*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the DiskCache. Look at that as a replacement of the Operative System's Memory Mapping. It handles loading/saving of pages from RAM to Disk:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/plocal-storage-disk-cache

You can change it by setting the global configuration "DISK_CACHE_SIZE" with the size you want to allocate in MB. Do this this before to use OrientDB:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.DISK_CACHE_SIZE.setValue( 1000 ); // 1GB
```

This setting is per-database, so if you have multiple database (not multiple users against the same database) you should assign it properly.

Comment: Thanks Luca. Is it possible to disable it ?

Comment: You can reduce it: OGlobalConfiguration.DISK_CACHE_PAGE_SIZE.setValue(<size_in_mb>)

Comment: From code: DISK_CACHE_PAGE_SIZE("storage.diskCache.pageSize", "Size of page of disk buffer in kilobytes,!!! **NEVER CHANGE THIS VALUE** !!!",
      Integer.class, 64)?

Comment: Sorry I meant: DISK_CACHE_SIZE

Comment: Ok i will try this. May be you could add this to your answer. Thanks again.